# Installing extensions via Magento connect not working after update to 1.9.2.0

Tags: upgrade, magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.0

After updating to Magento 1.9.2.0 the below mentioned issues
cannot install any extension from connect manager:

> Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1 failed error.

Comment: For static blocks see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block/73694. not sure about TLS sorry

Comment: I removed the static block question, which already has been answered [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/ee-1-14-2-ce-1-9-2-block-caching-update-has-non-unique-cache-keys-duplicate), so this won't be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem when trying to use the command line to perform updates.

I was able to fix this by commenting out line 377 of  *downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php*

Old code:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

New Code:

```
/**   Commented out to fix TLSv1 Failed Error
*        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
*/
```

I do not have a good explanation to give, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security

Comment: I agree with the fact that it's not really save to install extensions via Magento connect, directly on a live environment, but how is it safer to download an extension via a 3rd party "un-trusted" website? I don't question the morality of freegento, but as a principle, this is not safer.

Comment: @Marius agreed 100 % , updated the answer....