# Multi Store Footer Problem - HELP

Tags: layout, ce-1.9.0.1, multistore, xml, footer

I have 3 stores on my Magento installation. 
Each site has its own footer, with content coming from Static Blocks that are allocated to a specific Site View.

This is added to the page via cms.xml. For example:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links_ic">
<!--
The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
-->
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_ic</block_id></action>
</block>
```

This was fine until recently, when I noticed that suddenly all the sites had the same footer. I hadn't changed anything relating to the footers; although maybe the recent update to 1.9.2 was responsible?

Anyway, I don't understand why the footers now don't work properly. Please help, it's driving me crazy.
I don't know where to even start on this.

Comment: do they work correctly with the cache off?

Comment: Yes! I didn't think of that! Thank you so much! Ok, what can I do to make it work with the cache on?

Comment: Then check if this solves your problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/69215/146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil this sounds like a [bug which was reported in v1.9.2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870). Here it gives a tempory solution:

> Temporary Fix Disable the Blocks HTML output cache and the blocks
>   displayed are correctly.

I have also been told that the [Rkt_SbCache](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache) module fixes the issue.  I haven't tried and tested it yet but it may solve your issue.