# magento 1.9x switching widgets

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, widgets, opcache

My magento acts up weird.
I have normall magento caching enabled, but also OPcache enabled on php 7.1.10.

The problem i have is when i load the website in one browser i see the following:
[image: right view]
When i look at it in another browser(that previously loaded the website before the cache was cleared) i see the following (it grabs the html of a widget that shows above this one) :
[image: Wrong view]

Bonus; when i look at the 'wrong' browser incognito. It shows correctly. So if i'm correct the cache on the browser side isn't invalidated as it should after a cache clear?

How come, and more important. How can i solve it?

Comment: clear browser's cache

Comment: @Piyush i understand. But the problem is that users will also encounter this error... That's not done. For myself i don't mind. But customers/users shouldn't be able to get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation and searching i found a problem with the caching keys. I have the most recent magento 1.9.x version so i don't know why the problem is still here. But to solve it we have to patch a magento core file.

More info about this can be found here: [http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/69216](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/ee-1-14-2-ce-1-9-2-block-caching-update-has-non-unique-cache-keys-duplicate/69216#69216)
And for the problem if it's only exists in widgets on cms pages there is a [hotfix for it.](https://gist.github.com/tux-rampage/77b286f7973336877f7b#file-luka-mce20150805-1-9-2-1-caching-hotfix-patch)